# HTML includes without js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ssi

I am writing html for a web portal for my boss and using css (of course) for overall formatting.

First, he told me NOT to use css but to use html includes.  My understanding is that html includes are used for html repeated across multiple pages, not for formatting.  Also, in my understanding, html includes ALWAYS require js to insert them.  Am I wrong?  I would be happy to be wrong. I have a day of coding and markup ahead of me, I would like to start it making sense.

Comment: What even is an "html include"? In any case "don't use CSS" is a pretty ridiculous guideline here in 2019. (It was also pretty ridiculous in 2004, 15 years ago.)

Comment: @Pointy Maybe it is this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes

Comment: There was a short time where a proposal for [HTML Imports](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/imports/) as part of the Web Components effort, but it hasn't gotten out of editor's draft...

Comment: @halfer right, I can believe that, though I don't see what that has to do with using or not using CSS.

Comment: Ask your boss for a tutorial in these HTML Includes he cherishes so much, and how they solve the problem that CSS does. That'll shut him up real quick, or you'll learn something.

Comment: There's no such thing as HTML includes afaik, but I think he means the ASP command `#include somefilename.extension` that was standard back in those days when writing ASP.

Comment: OP meant Server Side Includes to avoid confusion here (he tagged it as SSI).

Comment: there is also possible that your boss had something to do with PHP , there is obvious to use includes file (also with html code) .... who knows :)

Comment: here is a non-standard solution
  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

Comment: server side includes used to exist...
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes

Comment: @NappingRabbit — They still do; they just aren't popular any more.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as an "HTML include".

There was a proposal for HTML imports but it is [dead in the water](https://caniuse.com/#feat=imports).

You've tagged this [ssi](/questions/tagged/ssi) which is a **server-side include** (which is a standard include mechanism that some HTTP servers support; [Apache HTTPD documents it](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html)).

Other mechanisms for including HTML include preprocessors like [static site generators](https://www.staticgen.com/), templates and include mechanisms provided via server-side programming, and client-side mechanisms involving JavaScript.

The closest HTML itself has to an include is the `iframe` which lets you embed entire HTML document in a scrolling box in the page. (You can achieve similar effects with `object` and `embed` but I'm yet to hear a good reason to prefer them to `iframe`).

---

CSS is the correct tool for presentation, but sometimes you need some common HTML scaffolding to apply the CSS to, and sometimes you want to have a single place to include all your presentation meta data (e.g. `<link>` elements) that gets shared between pages.